# If $f(n) = af(n/a) + c \log n$, how does $f(n)$ grow?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Question:
If $f(n) = af(n/a) + c \log n$,
how does $f(n)$ grow?

This is an attempt
to correct my answer here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188652/time-complexity-of-recurrence-fn-3f-fracn3ologn/1188673#1188673

It turns out my answer there
and my original answer here
were wrong.
My thanks to
 Henning Makholm
for showing where my error was.

My solution 
now agrees with others:

$f(n)
=O(n)
$
where the constant
implies by the $\omega$
depends on $a$ and $c$.

Proof:

$\begin{array}\\
f(n)
&=af(n/a)+c\log n\\
&=a(af(n/a^2)+c\log (n/a)))+c\log n\\
&=a^2f(n/a^2)+(ac+c)\log n-ac \log a\\
&=a^2f(n/a^2)+c(a+1)\log n-ac \log a\\
&=a^2(af(n/a^3)+c\log (n/a^2))+c(a+1)\log n-ac \log a\\
&=a^3f(n/a^3)+a^2c\log n-2a^2c\log a+c(a+1)\log n-ac \log a\\
&=a^3f(n/a^3)+c(a^2+a+1)\log n-ac(1+2a) \log a\\
&=a^4f(n/a^4)+c(a^3+a^2+a+1)\log n-ac(1+2a+3a^2) \log a\\
&...\\
&=a^mf(n/a^m)+cs(m)\log n-act(m)\\
\end{array}
$

$\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} i a^{i-1} = ((m-1) a^{m+1}-m a^m+a)/((a-1)^2 a)
$

where
$s(m)
=1+a+a^2+...+a^{m-1}
=(a^m-1)/(a-1)
$
and

(here's where my
mistake is:
I had the wrong formula for
$t(m)$)

$\begin{array}\\
t(m)
&=1+2a+3a^2+...+(m-1)a^{m-2}\\
&=((m-1) a^{m+1}-m a^m+a)/((a-1)^2 a)\\
&=(ma^m(a-1)-a^{m+1}+a)/((a-1)^2 a)\\
\end{array}
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
cs(m)\log n-act(m)
&=c\log n(a^m-1)/(a-1)-ac(ma^m(a-1)-a^{m+1}+a)/((a-1)^2 a)\\
&=\dfrac{ca(a-1)\log n(a^m-1)-ac(ma^m(a-1)-a^{m+1}+a)}{((a-1)^2 a)}\\
&=ac\dfrac{(a-1)\log n(a^m-1)-(ma^m(a-1)-a^{m+1}+a)}{((a-1)^2 a)}\\
\end{array}
$

and the numerator is

$(a-1)\log n(a^m-1)-(ma^m(a-1)-a^{m+1}+a)
=(a-1)a^m(\log n - m)-(a-1)\log n+a(a^m-1)
$

Since $1 \le n/a^m < a$,
$0 < \log n - m \log a < \log a$
or
$\log n - m \log a 
=O(1)
$,
so this term is
$O(a^m)
=O(n)$.

If $n = a^m$,
$m = \log n$
so
the numerator is
$-(a-1)\log n+a(n-1)
= \Omega(n)
$
and
$f(n) = \Omega(n)$.

So I was wrong.

Comment: I think your summation of $t(m)$ is wrong -- [Wolfram Alpha says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+i%3D1+to+m-1+of+i*a%5E%28i-1%29) you're missing terms with a factor of $m$, which will cancel out the logarithm in the end.

Comment: You are right. I corrected it (using your link) and it now is more correct:) Thanks.

Comment: in this question you solved it correctly?

Comment: This time I think I have. My answer agrees with comments and a solution here. I find it valuable to keep my errors visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case where $n$ is a power of $a$, say $n=a^k$, I get

$$ \begin{align} f(n)
&= nf(1) + \frac n{a}c\log(a) + \frac n{a^2}c\log(a^2) + \frac n{a^3}c\log(a^3) + \cdots + \frac{n}{a^k}c\log(a^k) \\
&= nf(1)+ cn\log(a)\bigl( \frac 1{a} + \frac2{a^2} + \frac 3{a^3} + \cdots + \frac k{a^k} \bigr) \\
&< nf(1) + cn\log(a)\sum_{j=1}^\infty j(1/a)^j \\
&= nf(1) + cn\log(a)\frac{a}{(a-1)^2} \end{align} $$

So for these $n$ we have
$$ nf(1) \le f(n) \le n\left(f(1)+c\log(a)\frac{a}{(a-1)^2}\right) $$

For arguments that are not powers of $a$, $f$ is certainly *increasing*, so what $f$ does between the powers of $a$ can at most vary it by a factor of $a$ from the linear growth above. Therefore,
$$ f(n) = \Theta(n) $$

Comment: What happened to the $c \log n$ (my $c s(m) \log n$)?

Comment: @martycohen: That's the last term in the first line -- I'm assuming $n=a^k$, so $\frac n{a^k}c\log(a^k) = c\log n$. (I admit I have trouble locating the error in your computation, though ...)

Comment: See my last comment above.